# Load url from array to ImageView in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, xcode, url

I need load url from array (arrayCoverURL) to ImageView.

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrayCoverURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: [take a loot at SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Comment: I need set image to ImageView in CollectionViewCell. Images are loading from url addresses in array (array of strings). How can I do it?

Comment: whats wrong with the posted code

Comment: Well, yes. And what is your question?

Comment: Ok, I solved my problem.  I tried make it with simple code, but finnaly I use SDWebImage. Thanks for it!!!! It really helped me!